# print statement in python along with json responses

Tags: python

i'm very new to python, and i looked at the python document, they have a print statement [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting), which looks similar to C languages printf. However, I tried to simulate it and it didnt work. I'm currently working on parsing the json response and if anyone could help me or even a bit hint it would be great. Thanks: Here is my python code.

```
   print('the inventory is {inventory} \n the orderlevel is {orderlevel} \n the slots is {slots}' %'inventory' = jsonResponse['dsn']['inventory'],'orderlevel' = jsonResponse['dsn']['order_level'],'slots' =  jsonResponse['slots']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing the syntax for the old printf-style format specifiers and the new `.format()`-based format specifiers.  The proper (new) way to write your `print` statement (with newlines added for readability) is:

```
print(
    'the inventory is {inventory} \n'
    ' the orderlevel is {orderlevel} \n'
    ' the slots is {slots}'
    .format(
        # Note that quotes around keyword arguments aren't allowed.
        inventory = jsonResponse['dsn']['inventory'],
        orderlevel = jsonResponse['dsn']['order_level'],
        slots =  jsonResponse['slots']
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with Python 3.6 onwards, you can also use [f strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) (tutorial link) in Python for a really nicely readable code that uses variables declared away from the print statement:

```
#Declare your variables like you normally would
inventory = jsonResponse['dsn']['inventory']
orderlevel = jsonResponse['dsn']['order_level']
slots =  jsonResponse['slots']

#print with an `f` at the beginning of your string
print(f'the inventory is {inventory}\n the orderlevel is {orderlevel}\n the slots is {slots}')
```